# Livecode iOS ERROR ITMS-90022 Bundle does not contain App Icon

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, livecode, appicon

I made an iPhone app in Livecode 9.6.1 and I saved it as a standalone app with all .png Icons and Splash screens uploaded in the respective sizes in the Standalone Application Settings.
I made the .ipa file and submitted it via Application Loader (also tried Transporter) and I got this error.

ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7,0. To support older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info,plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See
Same error for 76x76 and 152x152 pixels

I'm not sure if the following is of help,  but I noticed
- this is only the resolutions for the iOS 7 device icons?
- when I put the app onto a simulator or my personal iPhone device the app works fine and the splash screens work. But the app icon still displays as the default white one.
- if I right click on the .app file and show package contents I can see all the splash images but not any of the icon images files
- I can't open the .app file in Xcode to add these icon images to Info.plist

Mac Catalina Version 10,15,3

iPhone X IOS 13,3,1

LiveCode 9,6,0 (dp3)

Xcode 10,1 & 11,3 placed in the iOS SDKs

Thanks,

Gee

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you forgot to include the app icon or it isn't in the correct resolution. Check your [icon settings](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4603/l/685074-the-standalone-application-settings#icons) and make sure you include the icon for `iOS 7 Hi-Res iPhone`. It could also help to name your app icons correctly by adding the suffixes @2x and @3x to indicate high-res versions.

This means you have to make sure the following icons are present:

- iPhone: "MyAppIcon.png" (60x60)
- iOS 7 Hi-Res iPhone: "MyAppIcon@2x.png" (120x120)
- iPhone 6 Plys: "MyAppIcon@3x.png" (180x180)

Comment: I’m not sure if the problem is to do with the files I added or with LC/Xcode
I added ALL the icons in the tab for iOS
All of my icons are the correct dimension e.g. for iPhone X it's 180x180 px and iOS7 Hi-Res iPhone it's 120 x 120 px
Initially I exported each size myself in Adobe Illustrator but I even tried using app icon generators which gave me the @1 @2 @3 labels

Comment: Is there anything else while exporting I should be addressing: Should I merge my layers, PNG8 vs PNG 24, Transparency On vs Off, Interlaced On vs Off, None vs Art Optimised vs Type Optimised, something to do with the point (pt) resolution or colour space

Comment: Please refer to the [app icon specifications here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/). Make sure you are meetig all the requirements.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm meeting all requirements. Eventually I found a way to manually fix this. I put the icons in Copy Files. I edited the info,plist put that in Copy Files and remade the standalone app. This allowed the icons to show up on my physical device, allowed it to pass through Transporter without any errors and I have now submitted it to the App Store. So fingers crossed the Apple App Store approves my submission. I'll keep you updated.